# Looking for a simple SMTP server that supports TLS and can run on Linux

Tags: linux, smtp, tls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMTP server for Linux with simple configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/37142/smtp-server-for-linux-with-simple-configuration)

I'm looking for a simple SMTP server that I can run without too much installation hastle and that which can also support TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are too few requirements that have to be fulfilled. But the one and only answer to that question is [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org). It's the only server - that I know of - which ships with a working and secure preconfiguration.

Postfix and others are simple. This is what the S in SMTP stands for. And I don't know of any aspect of SMTP that Postfix can't do.

Comment: the 'S'imple is referring to the protocol.  Anyone who configured the older versions of Sendmail know that configuration of the daemons isn't always simple.

Comment: @Zoredache This is why Wietse wrote Postfix from scratch. And added a sendmail wrapper to keep the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix supports TLS and is fairly easy to configure.